# How to pass a model value of a jsp page to another jsp include page in java jsp

Tags: java, jsp

```
<c:set var="model" scope="request" value="${leadType}"/>
            <jsp:include page="leadCreate.jsp">
             <jsp:param name="model" value="${leadType}"/>
            </jsp:include>
```

im including a jsp page named  leadCreate and iwant to pass a model value that i have passed from controller to that jsp include page as a list of objects
i tried as jsp param but it is returning list as string . so icant iterate them using <c:forEach ...  statement in inculded jsp page...

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest small modification to address your issue:

Modify your `c:set` :

```
<c:set var="model" scope="request" value="${leadType}"/>
            <jsp:include page="leadCreate.jsp"/>
```

And in your `leadCreate.jsp` , just access or retrieve your list using :

```
${requestScope.leadType}
```